# How do I show that the mapping of orthogonal complement of $\ker T$ to $\mathrm{range}\ T$ is one to one?

Tags: functional-analysis

Having trouble figuring this out:

> Show that the mapping $T : (\ker T)^{\perp} \to \mathrm{range}\ T$ is one to one.

I have the definitions but am I suppose to set them equal to each other?

Comment: Is $T$ a map between Hilbert spaces?

Comment: Yes. T goes from H to H and is a bounded linear operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: for $\,x,y\in\left(\ker T\right)^\perp\,$

$$Tx=Ty\Longrightarrow T(x-y)=0\,\Longleftrightarrow \,x-y\in\ker T\cap(\ker T)^\perp\,\ldots$$

Comment: Thanks for the Hint, Don Antonio! I'm confused on your last part. What am I trying to get from that? That this is also the same in the range?

Comment: For any subspace $\,W\le V\,$ in an inner product space, what is $\,W\cap W^\perp\,$ ?

Comment: a subset of {0}

Comment: No: a *subspace* of zero, meaning: the trivial subspace $\,\{0\}\,$ itself!

Comment: perfect! so x-y will be in the trivial subspace. Thus, x = y and we are done, right?!

Comment: Así es, or: indeed!

Comment: Muchas Gracias, Senor! God bless!